# reading in files in python to find indexes of specific items

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a data file of values some of which have been added at a later date which are in the form: 999999.0 so I can pick them out to change.

test data I'm using is:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
999999.0
999999.0
999999.0
999999.0
999999.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

I need to find the indexes of the 999999.0 entries and have been using:

```
for i, j in enumerate(testdata):
    if j == 999999.0:
        print i
```

which works when I type in the data by hand as a list:

```
testdata = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 999999.0, 999999.0, 999999.0, 999999.0, 999999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

But when I read in the data from a file:

```
data = open("C: test.txt")
testdata = data.readlines()
```

It doesn't work! (I don't get any errors, just nothing prints)

How can I read in the data to find the indexes, or is there another way to find the indexes without changing the read in?

Comment: Note that your data typed by hand contains `float` objects, whereas the data you `read` from the file will be **`str` objects**...

Answer (score 3):

When you read a file, its contents are returned as a list of strings.  You need to convert the strings to numbers if you want to treat them as such.

```
for i, j in enumerate(testdata):
    if float(j) == 999999.0:
        print i
```

would work.

Comment: the (pseudo) "float" type used in computing is inherently inaccurate so equality testing on floats is better avoid. In this case you could more simply leave the original value as a string and test against `"999999.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

The data gets read as a string. Either do:

```
if j=='999999.0':
```

or

```
if float(j)==999999.0:
```